# How I open a single div while other all other get closed?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project and faced a problem. The problem is I have 8 div elements and they all are hidden. When I click a button the the specific div get opened. But I want to close all the other div's when one is already opened.

My code looks like this

```js
btn.onclick = function () {
 
 if (this.classList.contains('slide')) {

  number = this.getAttribute('data-num');
  this.classList.remove('slide');
  // set up the inner html
  showVideo(this.getAttribute('data-state'), number);
  this.setAttribute('data-state', 'on');
  buttons[number].closest('.chapter-card').classList.remove('yu');

 } else {

  number = this.getAttribute('data-num');
  this.classList.toggle('slide');
  showVideo(this.getAttribute('data-state'), number);
  this.setAttribute('data-state', 'off');
  buttons[number].closest('.chapter-card').classList.toggle('yu');
 }
};
});
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 tablet my-lg-5">
  <div class="chapter-card">
    <div class="chapter-title">
      <h2>Chapter 6: Name</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="chapter-button">
      <div class="toggle-button" data-state="on" data-num='5'>
        <div class="inner-circle">2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <section class="video"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: If using jQuery is an option : `$(this).addClass("on").siblings().removeClass("on")`, job done

Comment: The simplest method that I have found that always works for me is at the beginning of the function hide all of the divs, it doesn't matter if its what the user is trying to view. Then after that only show the div the user is trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

I guess yu is your class that decides if it's visible or not.

So before you toggle the right one off you could do:

```
// Get all yu elements
var allElements = Array.from(document.querySelector('.yu'));

// Loop allElements

for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++){
 // Remove the class
 allElements[i].classList.remove('yu');
}
```

So you hide them ALL to add one after this again.

Comment: Nope. It is for the animation purpose

Comment: Tell me the right class then? Be a little constructive man, we are just trying to help..

Comment: Look. When I click the toggle-button class then a slide class is added to the toggle-button which slide the toggle button from its initial position. Also when it have slide class then it insert the html in section with class of video. The thing I want to achive is that when any toggle button have the class slide then the other toggle buttons do have the class of slide